# Creating SQL view with XML data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, xmltable

I'm trying to create a view for this output but have received the error ORA-04044: procedure,function,package, or type is not allowed here. Changing the parenthesis will then result in invalid SQL statement or missing parenthesis errors.

The code is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW DQ AS
(SELECT
a.USERNAME AS USER,
a.ITEM AS ITEM,
a.BUSINESS AS BUSINESS,
a.ADDED AS ADDED,
(SELECT x.* FROM XMLTABLE('$Logs/Actions/Info' PASSING Logs AS "Logs"
COLUMNS
ITEM VARCHAR(30) PATH '@ITEM',
REGION VARCHAR(100) PATH '@REGION',
ADDED_NEW VARCHAR(60) PATH '@ADDED_NEW'))AS x)
FROM IDS b, IT_LOGS a, x
WHERE a.BUSINESS IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
AND x.ITEM=b.IDS(+)
AND a.ADDED BETWEEN TO_DATE ('1/1/2019 00:00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2/1/2019 23:59:59,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
);
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: for starters you're missing commas for your first 4 columns in your first SELECT

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I have the commas in on the file (another laptop) so that's not the problem. Will edit now. Thanks.

Comment: so make sure the code you're sharing is the actual code you're running...

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use Oracle reserved keywords like `USER` as column names if you can avoid it.

Second, you didn't show us your XML, so I had to guess at its structure. If your XML doesn't look like my example, edit your question to add it.

But the main thing is that XMLTABLE returns a table, so you should put it in your FROM clause with the other tables. There's [a lot of other examples on here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xmltable) using XMLTABLE that you can look at, too.

```
-- example data
with IT_LOGS as (select XMLTYPE('<Logs><Actions><Info ITEM="item1" REGION="region1" ADDED_NEW="added1" /></Actions></Logs>') as Logs, 
                    'user' as username, 'x' as business 
                from dual)
-- query
select a.username, c.item, a.business, c.region, c.added_new
from IT_LOGS a
cross join XMLTABLE('/Logs/Actions/Info' PASSING a.Logs
    COLUMNS
    ITEM VARCHAR(30) PATH '@ITEM',
    REGION VARCHAR(100) PATH '@REGION',
    ADDED_NEW VARCHAR(60) PATH '@ADDED_NEW') c;
```

Output:

```
USERNAME  ITEM   BUSINESS  REGION   ADDED_NEW
user      item1  x         region1  added1
```